# React-google-maps render directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

I am working with the react-google-maps package https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps to make a request to the google maps javascript API directions service https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple. I am getting the response back from the API as expected and can log it to the browser but I can not figure out how to get the polyline to render in the map component.

This line of code 
   `directionsDisplay.setMap(map);`
was returning an error  of

> "InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map  directions".

So I commented it out because it seems that the map is set by passing the `handleMapLoad()` to the GoogleMap component through refs. Some guidance on how to display the polyline would be much appreciated.

```
    /*global google*/
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap } from "react-google-maps";

    const GettingStartedGoogleMap = withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        ref={props.onMapLoad}
        defaultZoom={5}
        defaultCenter={{lat: 41.85, lng: -117.65}}
      >
      </GoogleMap>
    ));

    export default class GettingStartedExample extends Component {
      handleMapLoad = this.handleMapLoad.bind(this);

      handleMapLoad(map) {
        this.mapComponent = map;
        if (map) {
          console.log(map.getZoom());
        }
        const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        const directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); 

        // directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        const makeRequest = function() {
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        };
        function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
           directionsService.route({
             origin: 'San Francisco',
             destination: 'Portland',
             travelMode: 'DRIVING'
          }, function(response, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
              console.log(response)
            } else {
              window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
          });
        }
        makeRequest();
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div style={{height: `500px`}}>
            <GettingStartedGoogleMap
              containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
              mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
              onMapLoad={this.handleMapLoad}
            />
          </div>
         );
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use react-google-maps `Polyline` component to render direction. It gives us additional styling prop `options`. It is a way better approach than using the `DirectionRender` component. Here are the steps you must follow to render directions as `Polyline` on your Google Map:

- Use google maps direction service and extract `overview_path` from it like this;
  `overview_path` is an array of objects containing `Lat` and `Lng`.

...

```
DirectionsService.route({   
   origin: 'San Francisco', 
   destination: 'Portland',   
   travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,   
  },  
    (result, status) => {   
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {   
        const overViewCoords = result.routes[0].overview_path;   
          this.setState({   
            lineCoordinates: overViewCoords,
          });
      } else {
         console.warn(`error fetching directions ${status}`);
      }
    });
```

- Then pass these coordinates as the `path` prop of the `<Polyline />` Component;

...

```
<GoogleMap
    ref={props.onMapLoad}
    defaultZoom={5}
    defaultCenter={{lat: 41.85, lng: -117.65}}
  >
  <Polyline
        path={this.state.lineCoordinates}
        geodesic={false}
        options={{
            strokeColor: '#38B44F',
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 7,
        }}
    />
</GoogleMap>
```

PS. import `Polyline` from `react-google-maps` first:

```
import { Polyline } from 'react-google-maps';
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple and direct way to render directions in React using waypoints too

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { withScriptjs } from "react-google-maps";




import  Map from './components/Map';

function App() {

  const MapLoader = withScriptjs(Map);

  return (

<div className="App">
  <header className="App-header">
    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />

  </header>
  <MapLoader
      googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Key"
      loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
  />
</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And in your Map.js file

```
/*global google*/
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    withGoogleMap,
    withScriptjs,
    GoogleMap,
    DirectionsRenderer
} from "react-google-maps";
class Map extends Component {
    state = {
        directions: null,


};

componentDidMount() {
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    const origin = { lat: 6.5244, lng:  3.3792 };
    const destination = { lat: 6.4667, lng:  3.4500};

    directionsService.route(
        {
            origin: origin,
            destination: destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            waypoints: [
                {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(6.4698,  3.5852)
                },
                {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(6.6018,3.3515)
                }
            ]
        },
        (result, status) => {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                console.log(result)
                this.setState({
                    directions: result
                });
            } else {
                console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
            }
        }
    );
}

render() {
    const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
        <GoogleMap
            defaultCenter={{ lat: 6.5244, lng:  3.3792 }}
            defaultZoom={13}
        >
            <DirectionsRenderer
                directions={this.state.directions}
            />
        </GoogleMap>
    ));

    return (
        <div>
            <GoogleMapExample
                containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: "500px" }} />}
                mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
            />
        </div>


       );
    }
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: I'm also use this react-google-maps package. I want to custom marker in DirectionsRenderer instead of Pointer A and B, Any one explain me